# Global variables in Airflow

Tags: global-variables, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am trying to implement basic ETL job, using Airflow, but stucked in one point:

I have 3 functions. And I want to define global variables for each of them like:

```
function a():
   return a_result

function b():
     use a
     return b_result
function c():
     use a and b
```

And then use these functions in `python_callable`.

Defining as usual `global a_result` is not working. Any solutions?

Comment: When you return something in your `python_callable`, you can access the returned value if you pass the task context to the next operator. https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Thanks a lot! Can you share it as an answer, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment,

> When you return something in your `python_callable`, you can access the returned value if you pass the task context to the next operator. https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom

The following is semi-pseudo code that illustrates the idea

```
# inside a PythonOperator called 'pushing_task' 
def push_function(): 
    return value 

# inside another PythonOperator where provide_context=True 
def pull_function(**context): 
    value = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='pushing_task')

pushing_task = PythonOperator('pushing_task', 
                              push_function, ...)

pulling_task = PythonOperator('pulling_task', 
                              pull_function, 
                              provide_context=True ...)
```

Comment: Does this also work with non-python operators like a custom sensor?

Comment: @MaileCupo I think as long as you return something in your sensor operator this will work. You just need to pass in the `task_id`.