# How to use a python list as global variable python list with in @task.external_python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

### GOAL:

- Have a python list as a global variable between tasks.
- Currently it crashes at the 1st task.
- 1.) I am trying to have a simple python list that is carried from 1 task to the next and append a few string values to it at task 2. So the goal is to have 1 shared list.
- 2.) Even if 1 task fails it should just move on ad dotn care (obviously mark the task area failed)

### SETUP:

- I am on Airflow 2.4.1
- I use Airflow Docker and build a python environemnt that I have used many times and just works fine.

### MY CODE:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import logging
import os
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile
import time
from pprint import pprint
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
PYTHON = sys.executable
BASE_DIR = tempfile.gettempdir()

my_default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'email': ['some_email@some_email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False, 
    'write_successes': [],
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag_id',
    schedule='9 9 * * *',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    default_args=my_default_args,
    tags=['a', 'b'],
    ) as dag:

    @task.external_python(task_id="one", python='/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3')
    def first(**kwargs):
        task_id="one"
        write_successes = kwargs.get('write_successes', [])

        print(write_successes)
        write_successes.append(99)
        print(write_successes)


    @task.external_python(task_id="two", python='/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3')
    def second(**kwargs):
        write_successes = kwargs.get('write_successes', [])

        print(write_successes)
        write_successes.append(101)
        print(write_successes)


    one = first()
    two = second()

    one >> two
```

### ERROR:

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=test_global_variable/run_id=scheduled__2023-02-05T09:09:00+00:00/task_id=one/attempt=1.log
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.one scheduled__2023-02-05T09:09:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.one scheduled__2023-02-05T09:09:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): one> on 2023-02-05 09:09:00+00:00
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 239657 to run task
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test_global_variable', 'one', 'scheduled__2023-02-05T09:09:00+00:00', '--job-id', '72751', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test_global_variable.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpxldmrzpp']
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 72751: Subtask one
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {dagbag.py:525} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/test_global_variable.py
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {task_command.py:384} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.one scheduled__2023-02-05T09:09:00+00:00 [running]> on host 4851b30aa5cf
[2023-02-06, 12:24:43 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1590} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=me
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test_global_variable
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=one
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-02-05T09:09:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2023-02-05T09:09:00+00:00
[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'execution_date' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'data_interval_start' or 'logical_date' instead.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'next_ds' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use '{{ data_interval_end | ds }}' instead.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'next_ds_nodash' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use '{{ data_interval_end | ds_nodash }}' instead.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'next_execution_date' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'data_interval_end' instead.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'prev_ds' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'prev_ds_nodash' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'prev_execution_date' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'prev_execution_date_success' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'prev_data_interval_start_success' instead.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'tomorrow_ds' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'tomorrow_ds_nodash' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'yesterday_ds' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'yesterday_ds_nodash' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1851} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 188, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 370, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 678, in execute_callable
    return self._execute_python_callable_in_subprocess(python_path, tmp_path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 411, in _execute_python_callable_in_subprocess
    self._write_args(input_path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 381, in _write_args
    file.write_bytes(self.pickling_library.dumps({'args': self.op_args, 'kwargs': self.op_kwargs}))
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function first at 0x7f80ff76e4c0>: it's not the same object as unusual_prefix_6cc7442bed7c02593e3a29524b0e65329d9f59da_test_global_variable.first
[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_global_variable, task_id=one, execution_date=20230205T090900, start_date=20230206T122443, end_date=20230206T122444
[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:102} ERROR - Failed to execute job 72751 for task one (Can't pickle <function first at 0x7f80ff76e4c0>: it's not the same object as unusual_prefix_6cc7442bed7c02593e3a29524b0e65329d9f59da_test_global_variable.first; 239657)
[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {local_task_job.py:164} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-02-06, 12:24:44 GMT] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

### I have tried to fix it based on the following posts:

- I have tried global python variables that did not worked at all
- [Global variables in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792721/global-variables-in-airflow) - i have separate "task.external_python" that makes it not possible to use the following post.
- Mine is not a class issue - [List as global variable inside a class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705029/list-as-global-variable-inside-a-class-in-python)
- might be interesting but I have separate python venve for each task - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58804409/10270590
- I could not get Airflow XCOM working
- @TJaniF -> (I have retried this a 2nd time than it have worked but on the 1st run with the same code I got the following results:) I have tried the following code the long top bar is marked as Failed but a single square bellow marked as success but then there was no square below that square at all. I don't understand this

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from pendulum import datetime


@dag(
    dag_id='test_global_variable',
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,)
def write_var():

    @task.external_python(task_id="task_1", python='/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3')
    def add_to_list(my_list):
        print(my_list)
        my_list.append(19)
        return my_list


    @task.external_python(task_id="task_2", python='/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3')
    def add_to_list_2(my_list):
        print(my_list)
        my_list.append(42)
        return my_list

    add_to_list_2(add_to_list([23, 5, 8]))


write_var()
```

LOG From the succesful task

```
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.task_1 manual__2023-02-06T15:36:51.225176+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.task_1 manual__2023-02-06T15:36:51.225176+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1> on 2023-02-06 15:36:51.225176+00:00
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 249785 to run task
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test_global_variable', 'task_1', 'manual__2023-02-06T15:36:51.225176+00:00', '--job-id', '72908', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test_global_variable.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpuw6bfiif']
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 72908: Subtask task_1
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {dagbag.py:525} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/test_global_variable.py
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {task_command.py:384} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.task_1 manual__2023-02-06T15:36:51.225176+00:00 [running]> on host 4851b30aa5cf
[2023-02-06, 15:36:52 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1590} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test_global_variable
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=task_1
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-02-06T15:36:51.225176+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-02-06T15:36:51.225176+00:00
[2023-02-06, 15:36:53 GMT] {process_utils.py:179} INFO - Executing cmd: /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3 /tmp/tmd35abbbcv/script.py /tmp/tmd35abbbcv/script.in /tmp/tmd35abbbcv/script.out /tmp/tmd35abbbcv/string_args.txt
[2023-02-06, 15:36:53 GMT] {process_utils.py:183} INFO - Output:
[2023-02-06, 15:36:54 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [23, 5, 8]
[2023-02-06, 15:36:54 GMT] {python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: [23, 5, 8, 19]
[2023-02-06, 15:36:54 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=test_global_variable, task_id=task_1, execution_date=20230206T153651, start_date=20230206T153652, end_date=20230206T153654
[2023-02-06, 15:36:54 GMT] {local_task_job.py:164} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-02-06, 15:36:54 GMT] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

### Screenshot:

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious what your tried for Airflow XCom? The following DAG passes a list from one task to another using XCom via the TaskFlow API. Tested for Airflow 2.5.1, but it should work the same with 2.4.1.

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from pendulum import datetime


@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
)
def write_var():

    @task.external_python(
        task_id="task_1",
        python='/home/astro/.pyenv/versions/my_env/bin/python'
    )
    def add_to_list(my_list):
        print(my_list)
        my_list.append(19)
        return my_list


    @task.external_python(
        task_id="task_2",
        python='/home/astro/.pyenv/versions/my_env/bin/python'
    )
    def add_to_list_2(my_list):
        print(my_list)
        my_list.append(42)
        return my_list

    add_to_list_2(add_to_list([23, 5, 8]))


write_var()
```

Screenshot:

[image: Grid view]

Comment: I have updated my code based on your recommendation, I have added it to my main post with the.

Comment: That is quite odd. I added a screenshot of my gridview and I understand you only get one green square from task_1 but a failed DAGrun bar? Does it stay that way after restarting Airflow?