# How to use a python list as global variable pandas data frame with in @task.external_python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

### Goal

- I use the Docker 2.4.1 version of Airflow
- I use my external python virtual environment for each task
- I have a pandas data frame that I want to pass on from task to task.
- I my previosue question [How to use a python list as global variable python list with in @task.external_python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361423/how-to-use-a-python-list-as-global-variable-with-in-task-external-python) this was doen succesfully via a python list but when I switch to a pandas data frame the process crashes
- The first task succesfully runs

### CODE

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from pendulum import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


my_default_args = {
    'owner': 'Anonymus',
    # 'email': ['random@random.com'],
    # 'email_on_failure': True,
    # 'email_on_retry': False, #only allow if it was allowed in the scheduler
    # 'retries': 1, #only allow if it was allowed in the scheduler
    # 'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    # 'depends_on_past': False,
}

@dag(
    dag_id='test_global_variable',
    schedule='12 11 * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2023,2,1,tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    default_args=my_default_args,
    tags=['sample_tag', 'sample_tag2'],
    )
def write_var():

    @task.external_python(task_id="task_1", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
    def add_to_list(my_list):
        print(my_list)
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
        return df


    @task.external_python(task_id="task_2", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
    def add_to_list_2(df):
        print(df)
        df = df.append([19])
        return df

    add_to_list_2(add_to_list([23, 5, 8]))


write_var()
```

### ERROR LOG of 2nd task

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=test_global_variable/run_id=manual__2023-02-07T14:06:17.432734+00:00/task_id=task_2/attempt=1.log
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.task_2 manual__2023-02-07T14:06:17.432734+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.task_2 manual__2023-02-07T14:06:17.432734+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2> on 2023-02-07 14:06:17.432734+00:00
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 324831 to run task
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test_global_variable', 'task_2', 'manual__2023-02-07T14:06:17.432734+00:00', '--job-id', '74080', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test_global_variable.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpbm8tkk1i']
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 74080: Subtask task_2
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {dagbag.py:525} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/test_global_variable.py
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_1>, task_2 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): task_2>, task_1 already registered for DAG: test_global_variable
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {task_command.py:384} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_global_variable.task_2 manual__2023-02-07T14:06:17.432734+00:00 [running]> on host 4851b30aa5cf
[2023-02-07, 14:06:22 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1590} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Anonymus
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test_global_variable
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=task_2
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-02-07T14:06:17.432734+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-02-07T14:06:17.432734+00:00
[2023-02-07, 14:06:23 GMT] {process_utils.py:179} INFO - Executing cmd: /opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3 /tmp/tmddiox599m/script.py /tmp/tmddiox599m/script.in /tmp/tmddiox599m/script.out /tmp/tmddiox599m/string_args.txt
[2023-02-07, 14:06:23 GMT] {process_utils.py:183} INFO - Output:
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -   File "/tmp/tmddiox599m/script.py", line 17, in <module>
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -     arg_dict = pickle.load(file)
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on <module 'pandas._libs.internals' from '/opt/airflow/venv1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/internals.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1851} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 188, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 370, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 678, in execute_callable
    return self._execute_python_callable_in_subprocess(python_path, tmp_path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 426, in _execute_python_callable_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 168, in execute_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 191, in execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/script.py', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/script.in', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/script.out', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_global_variable, task_id=task_2, execution_date=20230207T140617, start_date=20230207T140622, end_date=20230207T140624
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:102} ERROR - Failed to execute job 74080 for task task_2 (Command '['/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/script.py', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/script.in', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/script.out', '/tmp/tmddiox599m/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.; 324831)
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {local_task_job.py:164} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-02-07, 14:06:24 GMT] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `to_dict` to serialize your dataframe as dict and recreate it from the other task:

```
@task.external_python(task_id="task_1", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
def add_to_list(my_list):
    print(my_list)
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
    return df.to_dict('split')  # <- HERE


@task.external_python(task_id="task_2", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
def add_to_list_2(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(**df)  # <- HERE
    print(df)
    df = df.append([19])
    return df
```

From the Airflow documentation of [ExternalPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#using-externalpythonoperator) (and [VirtualPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#using-pythonvirtualenvoperator)) about serialization.

> Your python callable has to be serializable. There are a number of python objects that are not serializable using standard `pickle` library. You can mitigate some of those limitations by using `dill` library but even that library does not solve all the serialization limitations.

Comment: It is not just pandas speciic what if I want to use Tensorflow tensor formats? 
So the basic answer that I can only pass between tasks traditional base python data objects?

Comment: Not only basic object but serializable objects for pickle module. From the documentation """Your python callable has to be serializable. There are a number of python objects that are not serializable using standard pickle library. You can mitigate some of those limitations by using dill library but even that library does not solve all the serialization limitations."""

Comment: This was a perfectly complete answer thank you ;)

Comment: My opinion is it's better to handle yourself the serialization (write a csv file for example, a hdf5 or sqlite database) and load it from the second task. Or if you trust the dataframe, use `to_dict` :-)

Comment: Fully agree! I just wanted to add that one way to add custom serialization to all XComs that are being processed is by overriding the existing XCom serialization and deserialization methods via a custom XCom backend. [Here is an example using csv serialization for pandas dataframes](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/xcom-backend-tutorial#step-6-create-a-custom-serialization-method-to-handle-pandas-dataframes).

Comment: @TJaniF. Excellent article!!! May I suggest you to use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` to avoid to handle manually file deletion (and avoid collision) or maybe better read stream directly with something like `output = pd.read_csv(response)`. Pandas can read bytes stream.

Comment: @Corralien thanks so much for the feedback! I'll create an issue for that :)