# How to have multiple input and output connection for an Airflow DAG task use a global variable pandas data frame with in @task.external_python?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

### GOAL

- I use the Docker 2.4.1 version of Airflow
- I use my external python virtual environment for each task
- I have a normal python integer that I want to pass on from task to task.
- I should start form 1 graph point the "start" than it should push it's result to x, y, z than all of the x,y,z should go to "compare" to pick and print out the highest value.

### CODE

```
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
import os
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile
import time
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import timedelta

import pendulum

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
PYTHON = sys.executable
BASE_DIR = tempfile.gettempdir()


''''For Tasks that are essntial and we want to know about the 1st faliure!'''
my_default_args = {
    'owner': 'Anonymus',
    'email': ['random@random.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False, #only allow if it was allowed in the scheduler
    #'retries': 1, #only allow if it was allowed in the scheduler
    #'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='sample_many_task_connections',
    # https://crontab.guru/
    #                                      0-7, where 0 or 7 is Sunday
    #  min  HOUR   DAY_OF_MONTH    MONTH   DAY_OF_WEEK
    #   *     *          *           *         *
    schedule='12 11 * * *', # IT IS AT UTC. EX.: 11:12am UTC = 11:12am GMT = 12:12am BST
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1, tz="UTC"), # this is from whre it starts counting time to run taks, NOT like cron
    catchup=False,
    #execution_timeout=timedelta(seconds=60),
    default_args=my_default_args,
    tags=['sample_tag', 'sample_tag2'], ### !!! also add 'xRetry' to tags so we see if a DAG has rety feature in it
    ) as dag:
    #@task.external_python(task_id="test_external_python_venv_task", python=os.fspath(sys.executable))
    @task.external_python(task_id="start", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
    def start(): # this could be any function name
        start = 1
        print(start)
        return start

    @task.external_python(task_id="random_function_x", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
    def random_function_x(start):
        import random
        print('start: ', start)
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        print('x: ', x)
        x += start
        print('x += start: ', x)
        return x

    @task.external_python(task_id="random_function_y", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
    def random_function_y(start):
        import random
        print('start: ', start)
        y = random.randint(1, 100)
        print('y: ', y)
        y += start
        print('y += start: ', y)
        return y

    @task.external_python(task_id="random_function_z", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
    def random_function_z(start):
        import random
        print('start: ', start)
        z = random.randint(1, 100)
        print('z: ', z)
        z += start
        print('z += start: ', z)
        return z

    @task.external_python(task_id="compare", python='/opt/airflow/v1/bin/python3')
    def compare(x,y,z):
        # pick the largest value and return it from x y z and return what value was te largest
        
        if x > y and x > z:
            print('x is the largest', x)
            return x
        elif y > x and y > z:
            print('y is the largest', y)
            return y
        else:
            print('z is the largest', z)
            return z
    
    compare([random_function_x(start()), random_function_y(start()), random_function_z(start())])
```

### ERROR

```
error DAG Import Errors (1)
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/sample_many_task_connections.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 3037, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2952, in _bind
    raise TypeError(msg) from None
TypeError: missing a required argument: 'y'
```

### Tried

- based on previosue Q&A I not resolve this issue - [How to use a python list as global variable pandas data frame with in @task.external_python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374582/how-to-use-a-python-list-as-global-variable-pandas-data-frame-with-in-task-exte) & [How to use a python list as global variable python list with in @task.external_python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361423/how-to-use-a-python-list-as-global-variable-python-list-with-in-task-external-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking the list of tasks being passed to `compare()` will resolve the import error.

```py
compare(*[random_function_x(start()), random_function_y(start()), random_function_z(start())])
```

But if you want to have 1 node for the `start` task, you need to only call it once. Try something like this:

```py
_start = start()
compare(*[random_function_x(_start), random_function_y(_start), random_function_z(_start)])
```

[image]

Comment: It is nice but I want to just have 1 starting graph point and from that it should go the the 3: x,y,z than it all should connect to the compare

Comment: That's because you're calling `start()` 3 times. You can set the call to a variable and use that variable instead if you just want one `start` node.

Comment: @sogu I augmented the answer with this. Hope it helps!